# Save multi image Multer

Tags: html, node.js, multer

I'm having problems saving multiple images using Multer

```
    <form action="/api/imagesSection" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="uploadedImages" value="uploading_img" multiple>
      <input type="submit" value="uploading_img">
    </form>
```

Here is the route:

```
router.post('/imagesSection', upload.array('uploadedImages', 10), function(req, res) {
        let timeInMs = Date.now();

        for(var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++){
            let imageS = new ImageS();
            let file = req.files[i].destination + '/' + timeInMs +req.files[i].originalname ;
            imageS.imageUrl = req.files[i].destination + '/' + timeInMs +req.files[i].originalname ;
            imageS.title = 'req.body.title';
            imageS.description = 'req.body.description';

            fs.rename(req.files[i].path, file, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(500);
                } else {
                    imageS.save();
                    // res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
                    console.log(imageS);
                }   

            });
        }
    });
```

As you can see I'm calling `save() in every loop One new ImageS();
Bust it just save the first IMG file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works asynchronously, thats why you only save 1 image.

```
         fs.rename(req.files[i].path, file, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send(500);
            } else {
                imageS.save();
                // res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
                console.log(imageS);
            }   });
```

instead of using for-loop, try to use forEach(), just like I do in my code.

```
var images = [];
req.files.forEach(function(value, index){
        console.log(req.files.length);
        var tempPath = value.path;
        var targetPath = path.resolve('public/img/flat_images/'+flat._id+index+'.'+value.originalname.split('.').slice(-1).pop());
        images.push('/img/flat_images/'+flat._id+index+'.'+value.originalname.split('.').slice(-1).pop());
        console.log(images);
        fs.rename(tempPath,targetPath,function(err){
            if(err) return res.status(400).end();
        });
    });

flat.images = images;
 flat.save(function(err){
   if(err) return res.status(400).end();
   res.send(flat);
 });
```

Hope, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your files all have the same `originalname` and since `timeInMs` is only declared once, before your for-loop it does not work as a unique identifier.

Have your tried logging the value of req.files.length? Does it return what you expect it to?

**EDIT:** You could try adding all the desired files into an array. Then you could save all the items in your array in one function call using `.create()` like so:

```
ImageS.create(fileArray, function (err) {
  if (err) // ...
});
```

Comment: Does it return what you expect it to? Yes i checked it already
And I must try what you're said

Comment: No my friend steal the same problem

Comment: I assume `imageS` is a mongoose model? You could write a .then() function to log each successful save to DB. That might give you some insight.

I think you are having problems since Mongoose .save() is an asynchronous IO method. You would have to either use async.each or batch add the items with .create()

Comment: Ok i'm gone a rey it

Comment: Just tell me please, What is fileArray?
ImageS.create(fileArray, function (err) {
  if (err) // ...
});

Comment: @JohnYaghobieh create an array[], add each imageS into the array instead of saving in the for-loop. Then after the for-loop you can call ImageS.create(theNameOfYourArray, (err) => { if(err) {console.log(err)} });

Comment: Can you tell me please where is the problem?